# how to use pandas convert_dtypes()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I see quite a number of questions regarding assigning dtype, but most of them are outdated and recommending manual assignment.

A new method `df.convert_dtypes()` is available, but somehow it does not work for my case.

When I load csv files, all column's dtype are object, and even after doing `convert_dytpes()`, dytpes are still object.

I would really appreciate if you can help.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=5)
df = df.convert_dtypes()
```

update to question. -----------------------
I found that one of the reason is I have 2 rows mixed for column names. when I load and modify the dataframe, somehow convert_dtypes does not work.
before dtypes are all object, after convert_dypes all changed to string.
Ideally I would want to see datetime, int, float.

I also found that if I modify the csv data manually to have only one row for column name, convert_dtypes works well.
But just curious if there is a way to make it work on pandas..

example data here

```
0   some descriptions   banana  pear    orange  cherry
1   Timestamps  Channel 0   Channel 1   Channel 2   Channel 3
2   2021-10-01_04:41:53.546 -374680640  8   23.834873   -3
3   2021-10-01_04:41:53.546 -374680640  8   23.827892   0
4   2021-10-01_04:41:53.547 -374680640  8   23.829638   -1
5   2021-10-01_04:41:53.547 -374680640  8   23.845345   -1
6   2021-10-01_04:41:53.547 -374680640  8   23.822659   -1
7   2021-10-01_04:41:53.547 -374680640  8   23.813932   -3
8   2021-10-01_04:41:53.547 -374680640  8   23.819168   -2
9   2021-10-01_04:41:53.547 -374680640  8   23.826147   0
```

and the code I ran

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=4)
df = df.drop(axis=0, index=0)
df = df.rename(columns={'some descriptions':"timestamp"})
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ','')
df1 = df.convert_dtypes()
df1.dtypes
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your csv and some outputs (`df.dtypes`)?

Comment: Depends on the data you are loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide some data? It seems to work fine to me:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print('pandas version:', pd.__version__)
print('numpy version :', np.__version__)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'string': pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=np.dtype('O')), 
     'bool': pd.Series([True, False, True], dtype=np.dtype('O')),
     'int': pd.Series([0, 1, 2], dtype=np.dtype('O')),
     'float': pd.Series([0.0, 1.1, 2.2], dtype=np.dtype('O')),
    }
)

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)

df_new = df.convert_dtypes()

print(df_new.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
pandas version: 1.3.2
numpy version : 1.20.3

  string   bool int float
0      a   True   0   0.0
1      b  False   1   1.1
2      c   True   2   2.2

string    object
bool      object
int       object
float     object
dtype: object

string     string
bool      boolean
int         Int64
float     Float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: OP probably have mixed datatypes in each column, possibly something like this [a, b , 1, 2]

Answer (score 2):

Just an update.

On `pandas >= 2.0.0` you can use the [new](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#argument-dtype-backend-to-return-pyarrow-backed-or-numpy-backed-nullable-dtypes) `dtype_backend` parameter with `'numpy_nullable'` on the `pandas.read_*` methods and in the `pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes` method.

Examples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, None]})

print(df)
df.info()

df = df.convert_dtypes(dtype_backend='numpy_nullable')
print(df)
df.info()
```

Output:

```
A    B
0  1  4.0
1  2  5.0
2  3  NaN

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   A       3 non-null      int64  
 1   B       2 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 176.0 bytes

   A     B
0  1     4
1  2     5
2  3  <NA>

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   A       3 non-null      Int64
 1   B       2 non-null      Int64
dtypes: Int64(2)
memory usage: 182.0 bytes
```

**Warning, this tends to consume relatively more memory than treating all your dtypes manually.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': ['d', 'e', 'f']})
print("--------DataType of DataFrame---------")
print(df.dtypes)
print("--------DataType of DataFrame after converting---------")
df1=df.convert_dtypes()
print(df1.dtypes)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you've done here in your answer?